# How to get ID of gmail using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-api, gmail, gmail-api

Currently I have list of gmail accounts, and I need to associate them with their ID's. For example the gmail I have as follows `test@gmail.com`, and I need to have its ID. I am quite confused with online examples. Please give at least ideas of achieving the result. Thanks before hand.

Comment: which id ? do you mean 'test' before @?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to have the user who owns test@gmail.com to authenticate your application using gmail api and Oauth2.

Once you have an access token for that user you can then make a call ot the user info endpoint

```
https://openidconnect.googleapis.com/v1/userinfo?access_token={token}
```

This will return the Google profile information for that user and it will give you their internal google user id.

## note

There is no way to get a Google user id for a user who has not authenticated your application.  You have to have someones permission for this kind of thing.